# Outlook Calendar: Add different calendar of same mailbox to an event

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-calendar

While creating an event in the outlook calendar, I want to add multiple calendars of the same mailbox in the event. I am not able to find any way of doing this.
I am using MS Graph for creating events on the calendar.
Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Create event API to create a new event in a calendar. But you need to note that the calendar can be one for a user, or the default calendar of a Microsoft 365 group; it's not for the calendar group - so you can't add multiple calendars. Here's the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

You can use Create event API to create a new event in a calendar. But you need to note that the calendar can be one for a user, or the default calendar of a Microsoft 365 group; it's not for the calendar group - so you can't add multiple calendars. Here's the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).